# Click event working, but not tap/touch. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript

So I'm using this js code:

```
var wrapper1 = document.getElementById("signature-pad-1"),
canvas1 = wrapper1.querySelector("canvas"),
signaturePad1;

var foremansiginput = document.getElementById("foremansiginput")
canvas1.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
if (signaturePad1.isEmpty()) {
    foremansiginput.value = '';
} 
else {
    foremansiginput.value = signaturePad1.toDataURL('image/png');
}
});
canvas1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
if (signaturePad1.isEmpty()) {
    foremansiginput.value = '';
} 
else {
    foremansiginput.value = signaturePad1.toDataURL('image/png');
}
});
canvas1.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
if (signaturePad1.isEmpty()) {
    foremansiginput.value = '';
} 
else {
    foremansiginput.value = signaturePad1.toDataURL('image/png');
}
});

function clear1() { 
signaturePad1.clear(); 
foremansiginput.value = '';
}

function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
var ratio =  window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
canvas.width = 250;
canvas.height = 150;
}

resizeCanvas(canvas1);
signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(canvas1);


$("#clear1").click(clear1);
```

Everything is working fine and dandy except for the touch/tap event.  I've tried a bunch of different methods, and Google is telling me that "click" should work the same as touch or tap, so in theory, I shouldn't even be having this issue...

How do I make the tap/touch event work the same as click?

As of right now, when I sign the signature pad, everything else works.  I was having an issue where if my final "pen stroke" was a click it would clear the value of the input.  However, I fixed that by adding the "click" event listener.  So now, with a mouse, I click and it adds to the value, instead of clearing it.  However, if I tap/touch (without dragging my finger), it clears the value.  I need that to stop.  I need the user to be able to tap/touch the signature pad without it clearing the input value.

If it helps at all, I'm using szimek's [signature_pad.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js) as well to handle all this fun stuff.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.